# How to get DD (Date) from DD-MM-YYYY HH-MM-SS IN sql AND vb.NET

Tags: sql, vb.net

I want only date number (DD) from full date format in SQL and VB.Net.

For example. I am having 11/05/2017 and I want only 11.

How can I get that.

Please suggest me the code for it as soon as possible.

Comment: "Please suggest me the code for it as aoon possible." Your problem is not more important than anyother. "as soon possible" makes me not want to answer.

Comment: As soon as possible? Well, what have you tried? Show us your current code attempt.

Comment: That date is not a valid date according to ANSI SQL.

Comment: What is your actual input - you say you're working with `DD-MM-YYYY` and then immediately afterwards say "11/05/2017". **hopefully** you're actually dealing with `DateTime`s rather than strings?

Comment: Thank you for your not supposrting responce. But I have found the answer.   MAX(DATEPART(DAYS,COLUMN NAME))

Answer (score 1):

In VB.NET:

This gets the day from any date

```
Dim day As Integer = DateTime.ParseExact("11/05/2017", "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).Day
```

This gets the day from the current day

```
Dim day As Integer = DateTime.Now.Day
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySql you can use `SELECT DAY('2017-05-15');`

Or you can use Extract clause

`SELECT EXTRACT(DAY FROM "2017-05-15");`

Comment: can you tell me how to implete it into the table. I am not getting it

Comment: Like if you are having column1 in table tbl1 which is of date type then you can use following query         **SELECT DAY((select column1 from tbl1));** OR **SELECT EXTRACT(DAY FROM (select column1 from tbl1));**

Comment: what if I want to apply this formula on current system date

Comment: Well in that case use the following query **SELECT DAY((SELECT SYSDATE()));** OR you can use  **SELECT EXTRACT(DAY FROM (SELECT SYSDATE()));**

Comment: I am applying below query but it is not working                                                   select extract(day from (select docdate from oniv));

Comment: You can use above queries  written by me as it is, as they will extract day from current system date. It's working. This is an example in [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bd5f6/5)

Comment: Thank you so much for trying for me..But I found my answer by own way after appling so many syntax. which is MAX(DATEPART(DAYS,COLUMN NAME))